# How to use different tcp algorithm in one ns-3 run

Tags: tcp, ns-3

I have a ns-3 setup with two containers of station nodes. Now I want to compare the performace if these nodes use different tcp congestion controll algorithms. I know to change the default congestion controll algorithm with

```
Config::SetDefault ("ns3::TcpL4Protocol::SocketType", StringValue ("ns3::TcpVegas"));
```

e.g. for TCP Vegas. But how is it possible to assign a speciffic algorithm to a specific node?
I tried it wit the `InternetStackHelper` and its mehode `stack.SetTcp(TypeId::LookupByName("ns3::TcpNewReno"));`
But this doesn't work for me.